# Add string to with zero to value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have table where I want to insert a value into a column which is unique and basically determined by 3 factors:

1. character R at the start
2. then an auto-incremental value
3. then n number of zeros (depending on incremental value)

For example:

- if `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Request');`

  - returns `1` then it will be `R0001`
  - returns `121` then it should be `R0121`

What I have tried so far is

```
DECLARE @RequestUid NCHAR(5)
DECLARE @maxAutoIncrement INT

SET @maxAutoIncrement = IDENT_CURRENT('Request');
SET @RequestUid = CONCAT('R', '0000', @maxAutoIncrement)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Request] ([RequestTitle], [RequestTypeId], [FromDate],[ToDate], 
                             [RequestDescription], [FormId], [UserId], 
                             [CreatedOn], [CreatedBy],[RequestUid])
VALUES (@RequestTitle, @RequestTypeId, @FromDate, @ToDate,
        @RequestDescription, @FormId, @UserId, 
        GETDATE(), @CreatedBy, @RequestUid)
```

This statement is used in a stored procedure.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please tag with your version and database.  Looks like SQL server.

Comment: added.. Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is called once, I would suggest format()

```
SET @RequestUid='R'+format(@maxAutoIncreament,'0000')
```

**Format()** has some great functionality, and well worth exploration, but it is not known to be a performer and should be used sparingly.

**Edit,** IF you want the number of Zeros to be Parameter

```
Declare @n int = 4

SET @RequestUid='R'+format(@maxAutoIncreament,replicate('0',@n))
```